# How to create unpublished page post for video using Ads api and what are the params required for create video unpublished pagepost?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Iam Using facebook ads Api.  i want crate a unpublished page post for video.  the Graph apireturns  error as follows 
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#353) You must select a video file to upload.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 353
  }
}
 any solution  for that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Change service call from  ← https://graph.facebook.com/ to ← https://graph-video.facebook.com/
then it will Works fine